# TinyMCE - How to add a button with a name

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I know I can add buttons in TinyMCE 4 using `addButton` . But when I use addButton and enter a title for it, only an empty button is shown in the editor with a tooltip that contains the content of title. How do I add a title, that is actually shown in the menubar, like for the save button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks to Eslam.

You actually just set the 'text' value of addButton:

```
$('#site_content').tinymce({
    setup : function(ed) {
            ed.addButton('name', {
                text : 'TEXT',
                onclick : function() {

                }
            });
         }
});
```

The documentation of TinyMCE is just awful at some parts, if you'd ask me

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create and render a button to the body element
tinymce.ui.Factory.create({
type: 'button',
text: 'My button'
}).renderTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only renders it to the body, I want the button to show up in the menubar, just like addButton does it